# Creating a scrollable block without using div overflow:auto or JS

Tags: html, scrollbar, css

I'm trying to create an element inside my html page that will contain a table but I want it to have a fixed height and a scrollbar. Since I will be sending this via email and some email clients don't support text-overflow, I want to be able to do it without using any overflows or javascript. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Email HTML has to be EXTREMELY old school. Think HTML4.01. Outlook uses MS Word 2007 as it's HTML parser. 99% of your fancy CSS won't work and zero JS will work. Let the content fill the email body and let the user scroll the client window.

One option that is common is to have "leader text", like the first 120 or so characters of whatever article you want the user to read, accompanied by a "read more" link that takes the user to the full article on the website. The purpose of your email should be to get the user to your website asap so you can utilize a browser and sell your content or service.